# Creating a Font Editor using JavaFX

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a font editor where the user draws the characters and I save them as a font.

I already have a javafx gui for drawing and what not but im having trouble how to convert the images to font. Any ideas on how to go about this? (Please if there are any other solutions on creating fonts without using Fontastic it would be much appreciated.)

Side Note:

Ive been looking into using the Fontastic Library but when I try to make a Fontastic Object (`Fontastic f = new Fontastic(this,"MyFont")`) I get an error that says `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Admin\Graphics\Project\null\data\MyFont\MyFont.dtyp (The system cannot find the path specified)`.

This is my code :

```
import fontastic.*;
import processing.core.*;

public class Blah extends PApplet {
    
   public void blah() {
        Fontastic F = new Fontastic(this, "MyFont");
   }
}
```

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blah b = new Blah();
        b.blah();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure the `null` in the path is normal ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing fontastic globally and did you install the package

Comment: I download the Fontastic.jar from https://github.com/andipollok/Fontastic/blob/master/download/Fontastic.zip and then just added it to my project. Not sure what you mean by globally.

Comment: Hi, This can go as comment and suggestions for questions. 
Do check this to enhance your answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You should try making a package for fontastic and then convert it to .class files. Then just use it as you would use a regular Java file ig.